# Searching the sum of a Key inside an ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, c, sorting, arraylist, binary-search

I need to search if inside my ArrayList there's the sum of TWO numbers which correspond to a given number X passed to the method.

I have those numbers in two different files - one contain the numbers and the other the keys.

What I do is:

-fill 2 different ArrayList with those numbers

-sort the one with the numbers which I have to search the sum so it's ordered

and then I don't know how to check if the given key is sum of two numbers contained in the array list. Any suggestion? I post part of my code, just the last try.

Here I sort the ArrayList and call the method elementIsContained on it passing "sums.get(i)" which is the number I have to search inside the other ArrayList.

```
 case "-a":
            buffer.mergeSort(arrList, 0, arrList.size()-1);
            for(int i=0; i < sums.size(); i++){
            elementIsContained(arrList, 0, arrList.size()-1, sums.get(i) );
            }
            break;
```

and then I was trying to search the sum in a dicotomic way but I don't know how to sum all the combinations to find the key

I was thinking to avoid the search on items greater than the key and searching on the others but..I don't know, I'm out of ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see the flow of operations (one possible solution)

1. Initialize a  HashSet< Integer > SET, insert all the numbers from the list containing Numbers into the SET.
2. start a loop and Iterate the list containing the keys. So for each iteration you have a KEY.
3. if(Set.contains(Sum-KEY) then you have a combination of 2 numbers such that the sum is equal to KEY.

Comment: I can't use HashSet I have to do everything with those ArrayList.

For example I have an ArrayList  filled with numbers: 

10 25 40 0 5 17 11 23 7 30 

and my KEYS, which are the numbers i give as n in the method (sums.get(i) - the sums I have to check in the other ArrayList)

35 22 42 8 11


This must return ok for 35 (10 + 25 or 30 + 5), 22 (17 + 5) and 42 (25 +17) and NO for the others because I have no combination sum which gives me those numbers

Comment: If you can not use HashSet but normal additional array is fine then in case the range is less then simply you can apply heading based on index value matching and get similar behaviour as of HashSet. If you can not use additional space then only way sorting both arrays and then start iterating the array 1 from start and other from end and check the sum, if sum is less than K (target sum) then increment  index of array 1 else increment index of array2.